# Cannot use Python's pip on Windows 8. "specified executable is not a valid application for this os platform"

Tags: windows, python-2.7, windows-8, pip

I seem to be receiving a unique error in Python 2.7.6 on Windows 8 64bit.  I was able to install Python perfectly, then was able to install pip using [this](https://zignar.net/2012/06/17/install-python-on-windows/) guide.  But when I got to step 3 and I tried to install virtualenv using pip it gave me this error:

```
Program 'pip.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1
char:1
+ pip.exe install virtualenv
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip.exe install virtualenv
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Also when trying to just run the executable it does this:[image: GUI or pip direct start error]

I've tried other installation methods such as the [pip packaged executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377781/362951), but it always ends up that whenever it/I get to the stage of actually putting it to use this happens.

Thanks guys, hope you can help!

Comment: Try running `python c:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py install virtualenv` and see if that works. It'll be run directly by Python, instead of relying on the compiled `.exe` file.

Comment: Try installing pip from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) and then check again.

Comment: Great! I'll make an answer out of it, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installed properly, `pip` should include `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py`, among a few other scripts. I'm guessing there was some sort of issue when you installed pip the first time, and these scripts weren't placed properly.

As a workaround, try [downloading pip](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) from Christoph Gohlke's Python Externsion Packages for Windows repository, which is my go-to resource for installing third-party modules on Windows. The installer should automatically detect your Python installation and install the programs and scripts appropriately.