# The specified executable is not valid for application in this OS

Tags: python

So I tried to install pip and I just couldn't get it to work. Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

````
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install requests'
PS C:\Users\User> python -c "import pip.__main__"
Program 'python.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1
char:1
+ python -c "import pip.__main__"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ python -c "import pip.__main__"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed ```
````

Comment: checkout this question solution for the same [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266185/cannot-use-pythons-pip-on-windows-8-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appli)

Comment: does `python -m pip` work?

Comment: Yes but pip install requests still does not work